# Is there a reason for keeping cloud-init after it has run?

Tags: ubuntu, cloud-init

As I understand it cloud-init helps initialize a cloud server. But after the cloud server is initialized is there ever any further need to run cloud-init? I would like to remove it if it is no longer useful.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on use cases also if you are terminating instances then it is okay but for long running instances actually you can do a lot even after your server came up properly, some use cases are : boot time analysis, managing metadata and so many other things.